# UIRefreshControl not working properly on tabbed application

Tags: uitableview, cocoa-touch, uirefreshcontrol

I have a tabbed application, and on the second tab there is a refreshControl, where the user can pull down on the UITableViewController to refresh the data.

In `viewDidLoad` I have the following...

```
UIRefreshControl *myRefreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[myRefreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = myRefreshControl;
```

Pull this down as many times as you want, and it will refresh correctly, calling `refreshData:`.

However, as soon as you go to a different tab, and then come back, it no longer work. `refreshData:` is never called.

By setting `self.refreshControl = myRefreshControl`, does it not persist when coming back to this view? (If I create a @property for a UIRefreshControl in my .h, and assign self.refreshControl to that... it doesn't persist either.)

Do I HAVE to put the above code in `viewWillAppear` intsead? Is there another way to assign a UIRefreshController to self.refreshControl ONCE, and not have to create and assign one to it each time on something like `viewWillAppear`?